# Go: read bytes into array

Tags: go

I'm trying to append bytes to an array in the following way:

Go

```
func readBytes() {
    b := make([]byte, 1)
    a := [][]byte{}
    for i := 0, i < 4, i++ {
        conn.Read(b)
        a = append(a, b)
        fmt.Println(b)
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Result from fmt.Println(b):

```
[2]
[5]
[5]
[3]
```

Result from fmt.Println(a):

```
[[3], [3], [3], [3]]
```

Why does it only print out the last byte sent?? Am I missing something?

Comment: Isn't the output for `a` *really* `[[3], [3], [3], [3]]`? What might this indicate about the object(s) represented by each index in `a`? Under which case(s) would the value's (of the object representing by each index) always be the same and be linked? (Hint: there are only *two* array objects in the code.)

Comment: yea you're right.. I edited it. I'm not sure what this indicates..

Comment: @user2864740, when its a pointer? cos I'm using make to allocate an array and return a slice that refers to that array.

Comment: @user3918985 ..its a slice, which wraps pointers to underlying arrays (so, yes .. you're on the right track).

Comment: Is there a way around this? I tried to declare b := []byte{} but I got empty slices.

Comment: @user3918985 See http://blog.golang.org/slices and https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks - the operation is generally considered a "copy". However, for this case, simply move `b := make([]byte, 1)` inside top the top of the loop, so a fresh "b" is made each time.

Answer (score 1):

`b` is a slice - and you're therefore updating the same underlying array each time you pass it to `conn.Read`. You can [look at this Golang blog post to understand how this works](http://blog.golang.org/slices).

Once you call `fmt.Println(a)` .. each slice is looking at the same underlying array.

You could fix this by instantiating the buffer `b` in the loop, or using an array instead of a slice.

Here's a working example that re-allocates the `b` slice inside the loop: http://play.golang.org/p/cN1BE8WSFE

It is essentially (with an `int` slice):

```
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    b = []int{i, i + 1, i + 2, i + 3, i + 4}
    a = append(a, b)
}
```